# how to get the selected value in drop down

Tags: php, jquery

Here is my link: http://vkacademy.in/medvanndemo/test/ type Class.I want to get the selected dropdown value in jquery. I have tried onkeyup,keypress, change and bind also. here is my code.

```
<html>
<script type="text/jscript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('#categoryfield').autocomplete({source:'suggest_cate.php', minLength:2});
});
</script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
//alert('ok');
$("#categoryfield").change(function()
{
var catid1=this.value;
//alert(catid1);
var url="sample.php?cateid1="+catid1;
//alert(url);
$.post(url,function(data){
//alert(data);
$("#option1").html(data);
});
});
$("#option2").click(function(){
$("#option2_error").html("Sorry! Please select the product.");
});
});
</script>

<body>
<form name="frm1" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="category" id="categoryfield" value='' class="buttonlength" placeholder="E.g. Tuition, Music, Dance"/>
<span id="option1">
<select name="pname" id="option2">
<option value="">Select the field</option>
</select></span>
<span id="option2_error" style="color:red; font-size:15px;"></span>
<br><input type="submit" name="sub"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here: I have given my link using jquery autocomplete I am bringing the data.but my problem is I have used change function. so I will not get the full selected drop down value.
I have tried bind,onkeyup,keypress, keydown nothing is working for me.

sample.php

Here I want to get only one value like Class I-V Tuition (All Subject),Class I-V Tuition (Maths).when echo it, it stops at class full value is not coming how to get the selected dropdown in  jquery.base on this In php I want to show the form in php.

```
 <select name="pname">
    <?php 
    $query=mysql_query('select p.p_cat as test from parent_cat p where p.p_cat like "%'. mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cateid1']) .'%" union select c.ch_cat as test from child_cat c where c.ch_cat like "%'. mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cateid1']) .'%" union select s.sub_cat as test from sub_cat s where s.sub_cat like "%'. mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cateid1']) .'%"');
    while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    ?><option value="<?php echo $row2['pid'];?>"><?php echo $row2['test'];?></option><?
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Don’t implement your own event handling “outside” of it, but the events that `autocomplete` provides. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change

Comment: my problem is ?Get the selected value in jquery autocomplete using on click. autocomplete is working for me

Comment: please see this <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
a = $('#categoryfield');
alert(a.val());

});
</script>

Comment: What about it? That input field has an empty value directly after loading the page, so this code snippet makes little sense.

Comment: thanks ,please check the link and type class and pick Class I-V Tuition (Science) . This is the output I want . but it picks all the class . I want only  Class I-V Tuition (Science) form. see my sql code also now i am trying to user where in union. that's why i used change or keyup to get the value. it does not give favour for us. now i am working with query.

Comment: I can’t understand what you are trying to ask here, so I can only repeat: If you want to get the value that the user choses from an `autocomplete` element, then use the event that this plugin provides for that very purpose.

Comment: see already autocomplete done here I want to get the dropdown autocomplete value and send to php. bind,keyup is not supporting . I could not change the auto plugin right now.because I have implemented in all files. I will work in my query.

Comment: any idea how to get that  autocomplete values?

Comment: By using the change event that the plugin provides. How many more times do you need this repeated …?

Answer (score 0):

try it $(this).val() instead of this.value;

```
$("#categoryfield").change(function()
    {
    var catid1=$(this).val();
    //alert(catid1);
    var url="sample.php?cateid1="+catid1;
    //alert(url);
    $.post(url,function(data){
    //alert(data);
    $("#option1").html(data);
    });
```

Comment: please check in same link I have echo the code.no result. it stops at class

Comment: any thing like this  $( "#categoryfield option:selected" ).text();

Comment: Even this is also not coming <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
a = $('#categoryfield');
alert(a.val());

});
</script>